# Getting null point exception when i declare latlong values globally

Tags: java, android

I have got latlong values using shared preferences and stored it as double values.
Declared latlong values globally.
Getting null point Exception.
Tried different ways of declaring values globally,but nothing seems working.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivityConnect extends FragmentActivity {
ImageView emerg;
SharedPreferences pref;
String vechile;
Double deslatituded, deslongituded, srclatituded, srclongituded;
private GoogleMap mMap = null;
private final LatLng end = new LatLng(deslatituded, deslongituded);
private final LatLng start = new LatLng(srclatituded, srclongituded);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_activity_connect);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("gps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        deslatituded = extras.getDouble("deslatitude");
        deslongituded = extras.getDouble("deslongitude");


        srclatituded = extras.getDouble("srclatitude");
        srclongituded = extras.getDouble("srclongitude");
        vechile = extras.getString("vechile");

        if (!Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet not available. Cross check your internet connectivity and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (!Utils.isGPSTurnOn(getApplicationContext())) {
            showGPSDialog();
            return;
        }
    }

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        final TextView txtDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeed);
        new Routing(getParent(), mMap, txtDistance).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, start, end);
    }
}

private void showGPSDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppBaseTheme)) // Theme
            .setTitle(R.string.gps_lable_gps) // setTitle
            .setMessage(R.string.gps_lable_warning_message) // setMessage
            .setInverseBackgroundForced(false).setCancelable(false) //
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Utils.isGPSTurnOn(getApplicationContext())) {
        onResume();
    }
}
```

}
        Logcat

```
9-29 13:40:56.383  32078-    32149/zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking V/RenderScript﹕ Application   requested CPU execution
09-29 13:40:56.393  32078-  32149/zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb7579cd8 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
09-29 13:41:01.527  32078-32078/zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-29 13:41:01.536  32078-32078/zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking, PID: 32078
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking/zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking.MapsActivityConnect}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at zybo.example.ramz.demo_location_tracking.MapsActivityConnect.<init>(MapsActivityConnect.java:62)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1089)
        at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)                                              
  at 
  android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
```

Comment: Well, your LatLng's are null because your arguments (Double deslatituded, deslongituded, srclatituded, srclongituded;) are null at this point...

Comment: Your getting values from **getIntent().getExtras()** not from shared preference

Comment: @Clairvoyant so? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. Actually my code is working fine. Problem is with the shared preferences. I haven't shared the correct values. Once i fixed, it is working. :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize with values.

```
Double deslatituded, deslongituded, srclatituded, srclongituded;
```

You declare the doubles, but these are objects, not primitives. Therefore the default value is null. And the unboxing tries to get the primitive like

```
null.doubleValue()
```

Make them primitive or assign a default value like:

```
Double desLatituded = new Double(0);
```

Comment: Hey, It is not working. In this case it takes my map's source and destination is 0. Please find my logcat output "I/System.out﹕ sbuf: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=0.0,0.0&destination=0.0,0.0&sensor=true&mode=driving"

Comment: Of course, my answer was only related to the NullPointer. How do you fill it with real data was not my scope :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your error. But one of the scenario is 
you declare class variables

```
private final LatLng end = new LatLng(deslatituded, deslongituded);
private final LatLng start = new LatLng(srclatituded, srclongituded);
```

Here deslatituded, deslongituded values must be null. Maybe this will the reason for the nullPoiner please check this.

You need to pass the values for this. Or just initialise the values like deslatituded=0 or something. This will save you from crash

Answer (score 0):

Try this (and make sure your LatLng variables aren't final):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_activity_connect);

pref = getSharedPreferences("gps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    deslatituded = extras.getDouble("deslatitude");
    deslongituded = extras.getDouble("deslongitude");


    srclatituded = extras.getDouble("srclatitude");
    srclongituded = extras.getDouble("srclongitude");
    // NEW CODE
    end = new LatLng(deslatituded, deslongituded);
    start = new LatLng(srclatituded, srclongituded);
    // END NEW CODE
    vechile = extras.getString("vechile");

    if (!Utils.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet not available. Cross check your internet connectivity and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if (!Utils.isGPSTurnOn(getApplicationContext())) {
        showGPSDialog();
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. This helped

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your extras has the key "deslatitude"

like:

```
 if(getIntent().hasCategory("deslatitude"))
  {
 deslatituded = extras.getDouble("deslatitude");
  }


Log.e(TAG, "deslatitude: " + deslatituded );
```

And if your log prints the valuew then check it for all (deslat,deslong,srclat,srclong)

Answer (score 0):

Are there any values in

```
     extras.getDouble("deslatitude");
     extras.getDouble("deslongitude");
     extras.getDouble("srclatitude");
     extras.getDouble("srclongitude");
```

there is nothing in intent extras.